# Which php framework has an extensive helper function library (for the lazy man)?

Tags: php, frameworks, helper

I've been using Yii, and it's good, but its helper library is lacking. I've been snooping around CakePHP, and it has some some nice helper functions, like `timeAgoInWords()` and `autoLinkEmails()`.

Is there a php framework or library that stands out as having a crazy good helper library? in particular, for *formatting*.  Plus,  what is your favourite function?

Thanks!

Comment: I would mark this as community wiki, as there really is no one true answer, its subjective to users opinions.

Comment: agreed, but i am not seeing the checkbox. are you able to wiki-fy it? thx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/community-wiki  Looks like it has to meet the criteria or a moderator has to decide to convert it :) Sorry about that!

Comment: yeah, send them to an 2-year old answer with 50+ answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a big fan of [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) as it has a very nice template system included for doing page designs/formating.

Answer (score 1):

[Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) has a pretty good one.